# Use encrypted - hashed e-commerce customer email as Google Analytics User ID

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, measurement-protocol

Is it ok to use encrypted - hashed e-commerce customer email as Google Analytics User ID?
I found different privacy policy sections about the use of PII in  Google Analytics. For example [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6366371?hl=en&authuser=0) it says , it is ok to use the encrypted hashed form of the Data . But [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/email) in the caution section it says we are not allowed to use the PII data. I will be using Measurement Protocol and GTM for sending the data to Google Analytics.

If I use a proper level of encryption + hashing , will that be ok to use the customer email address (in hashed encrypted form) as the User ID in google analytics?

Regards,
Lina

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes it is OK to use SHA256-hashed PII data** like you pointed out as **hashing destroys the original data, thus it's no longer PII**: [cryptographic hash functions such as SHA256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) are [one-way functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function), thus from the output you can't figure out the input (FYI you can brute-force the generation of inputs matching a given output - especially with weaker algorithms such as `MD5` - to break into a system - eg guessing a password - but for the purpose of hiding PII it still does its job: you simply cannot know with certainty what the original PII was, so mission accomplished as far as protecting PII).

**The only downside with using hashing to generate a User ID is collision**: SHA256 produces 2^256 possible outputs, so if you're really unlucky (# emails / 2^256 = chance of collision) **it's possible that different emails produce the same SHA-256 hash and thus the same User ID** in which case different users will be incorrectly identified as the same user. **To reduce chances of collision you could combine the hash with other attributes**, eg `{user_signup_timestamp}-{email_hash}`, **but the only way to prevent collision is to rely on a database ID for each user** as the DB will ensure each User ID is unique.